# How to include external modules/packages into python package/.egg?

Tags: python, setup.py, python-wheel

Is there a way that I can include external python modules and packages into my .egg file in the same way we build .jar files with external java libraries embedded within?

Specifically, I'm using the `langdetect` and `nltk` modules in my code. Is it possible to package the code with these modules embedded within, so that I can run the generated .egg file directly on a another machine without the need for installing these modules on the new machine?